# xcorr not working as expected with different length signals

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

This is my first using [xcorr](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html) and I don't seem to understand it. I have a signal `signalSubset` within which I'm searching for another signal `signalWhole`. The search signal (`signalSubset`) is known to be within the signal being search through (`signalWhole`). Here's the code:

```
% signalSubset really is a contained within signalWhole
areSame = isequal(signalSubset, signalWhole(1 : length(signalSubset))); % true

% same length signals - finds best delay (which is zero)
[acor,lag] = xcorr(signalSubset, signalWhole(1 : length(signalSubset)));
[~,I] = max(abs(acor));
lagDiff = lag(I);

% different length signals - totally different delay of -1518
[acor,lag] = xcorr(signalSubset, signalWhole);
[~,I] = max(abs(acor));
lagDiff = lag(I);
```

Why is it when the signals have different lengths during `xcorr` that the index `I` is -1518 instead 0 as expected?

Comment: What if you were to specify the [`maxlag`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html?refresh=true#inputarg_maxlag) property to an appropriate number (i.e. the length of your shorter signal)

Comment: I just tried this with `[acor,lag] = xcorr(signalSubset, signalWhole, length(signalSubset))` but still got better correlations far from 0. http://imgur.com/SuFe6C0

Answer (score 1):

xcorr is quite a messy function - whenever I want to calculate correlation's, I prefer to use either SPSS or R.

Nevertheless, in order to use xcorr correctly, you need to pre-align the size of your signals beforehand. The function does not do it for you. 
This alignment is just seing which is the shortest signal and add 0's to the start and end of the signal.

Then yes, you can calculate xcorr correctly.
Code:

```
if length(dist_RF)<length(dist_LF)
    diferenca_tamanho=length(dist_LF)-length(dist_RF);
    extra_zeros=floor(diferenca_tamanho/2);
    quociente=mod(diferenca_tamanho,2);
    % Adicionar zeros inicio
    temp=dist_RF;
    dist_RF=zeros((length(dist_RF)+2*extra_zeros+quociente),1);
    dist_RF((extra_zeros+quociente+1):(length(temp)+(extra_zeros+quociente+1))-1,:)=temp;

elseif length(dist_RF)>length(dist_LF)
    diferenca_tamanho=length(dist_RF)-length(dist_LF);
    extra_zeros=floor(diferenca_tamanho/2);
    quociente=mod(diferenca_tamanho,2);
    % Adicionar zeros inicio e fim
    temp=dist_LF;
    dist_LF=zeros((length(dist_LF)+2*extra_zeros+quociente),1);
    dist_LF((extra_zeros+quociente+1):(length(temp)+(extra_zeros+quociente+1))-1,:)=temp;    
end

[correl,lags]=xcorr(dist_RF, dist_LF, 'coeff');

if (max(correl)>abs(min(correl)))
    correlation_coef=max(correl);
else
    correlation_coef=min(correl);
end

delay_signals=find(correlation_coef==correl);
delay_signals=lags(delay_signals);

cross_correlation_value=correlation_coef;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I had a look at the code and saw that it puts the `signalSubset` into the center of the zeros. However, it still gave me 366 as the best index instead of 0. This plot of lag vs correlation scores looks like this: http://imgur.com/lArbjwD . It's so strange, when I run the same code with randomly generated numbers instead of my signal, I get a correlation spike at 0. My signal is just a normal audio signal. Is this a known weakness of cross correlation and is there any way to minimize this weakness?

Comment: Nice question @PhloxMidas for which I don't have answer for...
When using this function for physical signals (positions over time for instance), it works just fine.